# CSS Selector without an attribute - Selenium Webdriver - Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

How would I select the class "form-control" (which is a dropdown) for the "th" that equals "Pay From" using the CSS selector in Java?

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Pay From</th>
<td>
<select class="form-control col-sm-2 ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-model="payment.selectedPaymentMethod" ng-options="paymentMethod as paymentMethod.text for paymentMethod in payment.paymentMethods track by paymentMethod.paymentMethodId" name="accountType" required="">
```

I know you can do something similar to the following for 'nested' objects:

```
(By.cssSelector("table[class='table'] > select[class^='form-control']"));
```

but how do I utilize the "th" that doesn't have an attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(By.cssSelector("table[class='table'] > tr:nth-child(1) > th:nth-child(1)"));

Comment: In your browser (e.g. firefox, chrome, IE) right click on the element and choose Inspect Element.  Right click again on the html element and choose Copy Unique Selector.